# Compare two tables and get the difference between them

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have two tables: TableA and TableB.

I need to compare two particular column(AnsId & Content) from two tables and get their difference.
In case there is no difference is found then I should return *'process success'*, else return *'Failure'*

**TableA**

```
+--------+-----------+---------+-------------+
|   Id   |  RSCId    | AnsId   |  Content    |
+--------+-----------+---------+-------------+
|    1   |   12      |  1      | Test data.  |
|    2   |   12      |  0      | Sample Test.|
|    3   |   12      |  5      | Test data.  |
|    4   |   12      |  7      | Test Data.  |
|    5   |   12      |  46     | Test datas. |
+--------+-----------+---------+-------------+
```

TableB

```
    +--------+-----------+---------+-------------+
    |   Id   |  RSCId    | AnsId   |  Content    |
    +--------+-----------+---------+-------------+
    |    1   |   35      |  2      | Test .      |
    |    2   |   35      |  0      | Sample Test.|
    |    3   |   35      |  5      | Test data.  |
    |    4   |   35      |  7      | Test Data.  |
    |    5   |   35      |  46     | Test datas. |
    +--------+-----------+---------+-------------+
```

Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

```
select case when sum(case when a.ansid is null or b.ansid is null 
                          then 1
                     end) > 0 
            then 'mismatch'
            else 'ok'
       end as result
from tableA a
full outer join tableB b on a.ansid = b.ansid and a.content = b.content
```

Comment: i tried your query.But i need a single output saying "Two tables are mismatched"